# Spin Orbit Coupling term

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, nuclear-physics

I was seeing this enlightening video of DrPhysics on Spin Orbit Coupling:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aftOY3OkAgA&list=PLF15670EECA944A13&index=9

And I think there is a mistake.

Around min 15:00 he assumes that $s(s+1) = 3/4$ **always**, which I think it is not true. We know that $s = \pm 1/2$

When he proceeds to compute the contribution of the $LS$ term when $l = 0$ for $s = 1/2$, he gets $LS = 0$  (which is correct).

If you compute the contribution of the $LS$ term when $l = 0$ for $s = -1/2$, you get $LS = 0$ as well (which seems reasonable).

Then he computes the LS term when $l>0$.

First, he goes with $j = l + 1/2$, getting $LS = \frac{l \hbar^2}{2}$ (I agree).

But know he goes with $j = l - 1/2$, getting $LS = -\frac{(l+1)\hbar^2}{2}$ **(I do not agree)**

He got this result because he assumed around min 15:00 that $s(s+1) = 3/4$ **always**...

**What I get using** $s = -1/2$ **is** $LS = -\frac{l\hbar^2}{2}$

Who's wrong then?

**EDIT**

OK so $s = 1/2$ always because the spin of the electron is always $1/2$ **but why?** (I know this has to be trivial, it has to be based on $S = \hbar\sqrt{s(s+1)}$ but don't see how to prove it).

Then DrPhysics is right asserting $LS = -\frac{(l+1)\hbar^2}{2}$ for $j = l - 1/2$.

**But there is another issue...**

When he calculates the $LS$ term when $l = 0$ for $s = 1/2$, he gets $LS = 0$. In that calculation he used $m_s = 1/2$ while computing $j$

**But why doesn't he calculate** $l = 0$ **for** $s = 1/2$ **and** $m_s = -1/2$ **while computing** $j$? Actually, you get $LS = 1$ so I must be missing something here...

The calculation is:

$$J = (L + S)^2$$

$$LS= \frac{J^2 -L^2 -S^2}{2} = \hbar^2[\frac{j(j+1) -l(l+1) -s(s+1)}{2}] = 1$$

Where $l = 0$, $s = 1/2$ and $m_s = -1/2$ (recalling that $j=l+m_s$):

I am sure I have to be missing something on $j=l+m_s$. Note that I regarded $m_s$ as the projection of S on an axis (let's say $z$).

Comment: There is a notation misconception here. s is the spin quantum number of the electron and it is always 1/2 (S^2=hbar^2 s(s+1)). On the other hand, the projection of the spin along the z axes Sz is what takes the values (+/-)hbar/2. This is conventionally denoted as ms=(+/-)1/2 but people tend to also use s for ms making analysis such as the above not so clear. Make sure to know the conventions that are used!

Comment: @PanosC.I have seen all the time that the total angular momentum is $j = l + s$. But based on official notation has to be $j = l + m_s$ instead, isn't it?

Comment: $J=L+S$ and $m_J=m_L+m_S$.

Comment: @JD_PM when adding angular momenta $j$ runs from $|l - s|$ to $l+s$ in integer steps, and $m_j$ runs from $-j$ to $j$ for a given $j$ in integer steps as well.

Comment: Thank you all, I see now my mistakes. One more thing; how can I show that the spin quantum number of the electron is always $1/2$?

Comment: You cannot do that using (non-relativistic) quantum mechanics (i.e. from Shcroedinger's equation). It was experimentally observed that when an electron beam passes through an oriented magnetic field, it splits into 2 beams (Stern-Gerlach experiment). This 2 is the number of possible valus of ms (2s+1), thus s=1/2. You can, however, derive that the electron (and the positron) has spin 1/2 from Dirac's equation.